# java filter hashmap subset and sort its values without loosing entire hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, testng, java-stream

As an input I have a list of IMethodInstance. Here's what I want to do with it:

1. group by class these entities are part of into `Map<Class, List<IMethodInstance>>`
2. filter classes inside map by predicate
3. Inside filtered classes sort `List<IMethodInstance>` by comparator
4. Collect map from step 1 into `List<IMethodInstance>`

This is what I have at the moment:

```
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    Map<Object, List<IMethodInstance>> groups =  methods.stream().collect(groupingBy(IMethodInstance::getInstance));

    Map<Object, List<IMethodInstance>> classesWithMethodsInOrder = groups.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> ReflectionUtils.shouldBeInvoked(entry.getKey().getClass(), OrderByDeclarationListener.class))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().sorted(byDeclaration()).collect(toList())));

    groups.putAll(classesWithMethodsInOrder);

    return groups.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e-> e.getValue().stream()).collect(toList());
}
```

This code works fine but I really want to have it as one single chain of calls. Is it possible? I need some way to filter classes in a map but without loosing other classes which values are not going to be sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requesting reviews of working code is off-topic on StackOverflow. Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This already an obfuscated mess, why would you want to make it even more so?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson  how would you solve this without mess?

Comment: what is `context` even used for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want this...

```
public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    return methods.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(IMethodInstance::getInstance))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> 
            ReflectionUtils.shouldBeInvoked(e.getKey().getClass(), OrderByDeclarationListener.class) ?  
            e.getValue().stream().sorted(byDeclaration()) : 
            e.getValue().stream())
        .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner to me. Thanks.